# Why input value is empty after reset?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular8

I have reference to input element:

```
  @ViewChild("inputSearch", {
    static: false
  })
```

Template is:

```
<input tabindex="0" type="text" (keydown)="keydownInputSearch($event)" #inputSearch autocomplete="off" autofocus />
<div class="searchWrapperBtn" (click)="reset()"></div>
```

Where reset is:

```
 public reset(): void {
    this.inputSearch.nativeElement.value = "";
  }
```

Why after `reset()` input value it is empty in input element but present in `{{inputSearch.value}}`

Comment: Can you please reproduce it in stackblitz?

Comment: Why are you directly interacting with the DOM when you have Angular data binding?

Comment: Do you mean to use ngModel?

Comment: @OPV you can use `template-driven` and `reactive-from` both.

Comment: I know but why in this case does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling view child properly, 
you chould do this

```
 @ViewChild('inputSearch', { static: false}) inputSearch: ElementRef;
```

Please take a look at this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hqsru4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)